# Trying to do a POST from SP to Service Now

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs, cors

I have been trying to do a post in Service Now through an angularjs form in SP, however I am always getting a CORS error. I've taken all CORS rules from Service Now and still am getting this error and started to think that it might be SP...

This is my header:

```
$http({
   method: "POST",
   url: "https://mycompany.service-now.com/api/now/table/u_application_request",
   data: JSON.stringify(requestItem),
   withCredentials: true,
   headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded,
        'Allow-Control-Access-Origin': 'https://myCompany.sharepoint.com'
   }
})
```

And I keep getting this response:

```
Failed to load https://myCompany.service-now.com/api/now/table/u_application_request: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://myCompany.sharepoint.com' is therefore not allowed access.
angular.js:14525 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"https://myCompany.service-now.com/api/now/table/u_application_request","data":"{\"u_short_description\":\"hiqhi\",\"sys_created_by\":14,\"u_state\":\"Functionality Requests\",\"u_description\":\"hi\",\"u_configuration_item\":\"Browser: Chrome. Version: 65. OS: Windows. Plugins: Chrome PDF Plugin/ Chrome PDF Viewer/ Native Client/ Widevine Content Decryption Module/ \",\"u_work_notes\":\"https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite\"}","withCredentials":true,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Authorization":"Basic U05CcDDSAWE1ZXN0S4NQOgNOU1WernRyQ2JhdTYwTg=="}},"statusText":""}
(anonymous) @ angular.js:14525
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11008
g @ angular.js:16860
$digest @ angular.js:17971
$apply @ angular.js:18269
l @ angular.js:12387
e @ angular.js:12551
error (async)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12554
p @ angular.js:12332
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12084
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16832
$digest @ angular.js:17971
$apply @ angular.js:18269
l @ angular.js:12387
A.onload @ angular.js:12541
load (async)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12524
p @ angular.js:12332
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12084
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16832
$digest @ angular.js:17971
$apply @ angular.js:18269
(anonymous) @ angular.js:26999
hg @ angular.js:3734
d @ angular.js:3722
angular.js:12587 XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "https://myCompany.service-now.com/api/now/table/u_application_request".
```

For what I notice at the end, it does load the SNOW site, but does not perform the POST method.